# merging columns from other files into one file

Tags: perl, python-3.x, numpy, pandas

I have multiple files and I need it be combined as single file with second columns (from all other files) added to the first file.
my file looks like this,

```
                      Nur of input reads    |   33
                    Ave input read length   |   20
                              UNIQUE READS:
                                Uni  number |   25
                               Uni  reads % |   74.40%
```

and all other files have same format as above I want the second columns from all other files to be added unto first file and make it as one file as follows,

```
               sample_1  sample_2  .....    sample_n
     Number      340        570      490
    Average        201       201      201
   niquely number  27096     29788    39870
       %           79.60%    80.1%     70 %
```

I tried in unix as

```
`paste file_1 file_2 ....file_n`
```

but the resulted file  looks clumsy also there is no header added to it with file name . Any solutions in Perl or python is appreciated..
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Python-pandas solution**

Key is function [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-read-csv-table):

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(files, names=column, sep='|', header=None, usecols=[1])
```

Set `name` to `column` (list from variable), doesn't read first row as header (`header=None`) and read only second column (`usecols=[1]`). Separator is `'|'`.

The third row's value is `NaN`, so it is removed by `df1 = df1.dropna()`.
Then `df1` is append to `df` and last is set index from list to output `df`.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

idx = ['Number', 'Average', 'niquely number', '%']
df = pd.DataFrame()
i = 0

for files in glob.glob('dir/*.txt'):

    i = i + 1
    column = ['sample_' + str(i)]

    df1 = pd.read_csv(files, names=column, sep='|', header=None, usecols=[1])
    #print df1   
    #remove NaN value from df1
    df1 = df1.dropna()
    #concat df1 to df
    df = pd.concat([df, df1], axis=1)

#add column idx do df
df['idx'] = pd.Series(idx, index=df.index)
#set index from column idx
df = df.set_index('idx')
#remove index name
del df.index.name

print df
```

Output:

```
                 sample_1   sample_2
Number                330         30
Average               201        201
niquely number         25         44
%                  74.40%     54.40%
```

file 1.txt

```
Nur of input reads    |   330
                    Ave input read length   |   201
                              UNIQUE READS:
                                Uni  number |   25
                               Uni  reads % |   74.40%
```

file2.txt

```
Nur of input reads    |   30
                    Ave input read length   |   201
                  UNIQUE READS:
                                Uni  number |  44
                               Uni  reads % |   54.40%
```

Answer (score 1):

In perl, perhaps something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %data;
my @headers = ( "Number", "Average", "niquely number", "%" );

#iterate files called "sample_*.txt"
foreach my $filename ( glob "sample_*.txt" ) {
    #open them for reading
    open( my $input, '<', $filename ) or die $!;

    my %stuff;
    while (<$input>) {
        chomp; # strip trailing linefeeds
        #split on "|"
        my ( $key, $value ) = split '\|';
        #strip leading/trailing whitespace from the key. 
        $key =~ s/^\s*//g;
        $key =~ s/\s*$//g;

        #insert into hash (does this need some whitespace cleaning too?)
        $stuff{$key} = $value;
    }
    close($filename);

    #insert into hash of hashes
    $data{$filename} = \%stuff;
}

my @file_order = sort keys %data;
print join( "\t", "", @file_order ), "\n";
foreach my $key (@headers) {
    print join( "\t", $key, map { $_->{$key} } @data{@file_order} ), "\n";
}
```

Comment: Hello Thank you for script, but I just edited a little about my sample file in above question, because this script is throwing an error as, Use of uninitialized value in join or string at script.pl line 34

Comment: Yep. You've changed your data, so the script as written doesn't work. That's quite a normal state of affairs. I'm sure you can you the script as a starting point for how to open and process a file though.